# Move the figure caption to the right?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I want to move the caption to be underneath the image, I used `\hspace*{-3cm}` to move the image to the left but the caption did not move with it the full code is

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering 
%DSOI 5V
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \hspace*{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=1.6\linewidth]{Figures/sec_16-46_3.pdf}
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfil 
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \hspace*{-1.5cm}\includegraphics[width=1.6\linewidth]{Figures/sec_614-644_3.pdf}
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}\hfil 
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
  \hspace{3cm}\includegraphics[width=1.6\linewidth]{Figures/sec_852-882_3.pdf}
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Please advice on how to resolve this.

Comment: Note that \caption starts and stops with a \par and uses the entire available width.  You would have to put it into a separate minipage to move it left or right.

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to do that with the `floatrow` package, which defines a `subfloatrow` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{qqquad}{\hskip 2.5em}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\floatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qqquad}
 \ffigbox{%
 \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\ffigbox[.25\textwidth]{\caption{image1}\label{fig:1}}
 {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_16-46_3.pdf}}
\ffigbox[.25\textwidth]{\caption{image2}\label{fig:2}}
 {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_614-644_3.pdf}}
\ffigbox[.25\textwidth]{\caption{image3}\label{fig:3}}
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_852-882_3.pdf}}
\end{subfloatrow}}%
{\caption{Three images}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to add another row of images?

Comment: You simply add another subfloatrow environment.  B.t.w., the `\ffigbox`  command can take an optional argument, which set the width of the minipage containing the subfigure, so that you can set the width of the caption (the default is `\FBwidth` – the width of the image, but nothing forbids to use, say, 1.25\FBwidth).

Comment: Hello, for some reason your code doesn't work the error in \ffigbox is undefined control sequence, I used the packages in the example

Comment: Could you post a small (yet complete) code reproducing the problem? Are you sure  floatrow is installed?

Answer (score 0):

`[singlelinesheck=off]` will stop the caption from being centered. Your best bet is to apply the `\hspace*` to the entire subfigure (which is basically a minipage). I would replace `[width=1.6\linewidth]` with `[width=\linewidth]` and stop trying to overlap subfigures. If you aren't happy with the spacing, use `\hfill` instead of `\hfil` and adjust the subfigure widths.

Since floatrow is on my "packages to avoid" list, here is an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_16-46_3.pdf}
  \caption{image1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_614-644_3.pdf}
  \caption{image2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/sec_852-882_3.pdf}
  \caption{image3}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]